# Outbound Email Cipher Strength

Tags: exchange-2010, tls, ssl

Is it possible to select a specific cipher strength for outbound mail using TLS in Exchange 2010?  I need it to use cipher strength AES256-SHA instead of AES128-SHA.  What's strange is that my inbound mail receives as AES256-SHA but outbound is 128.  Is this normal behaviour?  Does anyone have any tips on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer can be found at: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrgeneral/thread/5830c533-38eb-4d88-92fe-6e1a02d7bac4

Simple gpedit.msc SSL cipher order change.

Comment: We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This may theoretically answer the question however, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.